# the use of articles with ing-forms modyfied by of phrase

Tags: grammar, articles

> Buying of books/selling of books

What article should I use before **buying/selling**? All examples I saw on the internet have **"the"** before **buying/selling**. Why?

Answer (score 1):

They are preceded by the definite article as they basically become a noun. 
"Ing" in this case is used as a suffix to form a noun.

*To do the washing* -

Comment: Yes. But it is an uncountable noun, it can be used with no article whatsoever. Why is "the" article used in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a deverbal noun, or the progressive form of a verb being used as a noun.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Roles_of_%22gerund%22_clauses_in_a_sentence -- in particular, the sentence, "Her playing of the Bach fugues was inspiring." In general, when you have a noun phrase of the form "*VERB*-ing of *X*," you need some kind of article or possessive pronoun before it. I am not sure if there is a particular name for this rule, but it sounds incorrect to omit the article (or possessive pronoun).